# change dropdown value when checkbox is selected

Tags: jquery, forms, checkbox

I have this form and I want to keep the highest value in dropdown content when a checkbox is checked:

```
<html>
<head><title>Check Box</title>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script> 

</head>
<form>
<input type="checkbox" value="0" id="chk">Other
<input type="checkbox" value="1" id="chk1">Moderate incident
<input type="checkbox" value="2" id="chk2">Signifiant indcident
<input type="checkbox" value="3" id="chk3">Weather
<input type="checkbox" value="4" id="chk4">Severe
<input type="checkbox" value="2" id="chk5">Signifiant incident
<select id="test">
<option value="0">0 - Nothing important</option>
<option value="1">1 - Moderate incident</option>
<option value="2">2 - Signifiant incident</option>
<option value="3">3 - Weather Conditions</option>
<option value="4">4 - Severe incident</option>
</select>

</form>
<script>
$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){

    if ($(this).is(':checked'))
        $("#test").val($(this).val());
});
</script>
</html>
```

When a checkbox is checked the value from dropdown changes, but if the value from checkbox is smaller than the one already checked I don't want to change the value from dropdown, I want the highest value to remain in dropdown.

Ex: if in dropdown the highest value is 3 and i check value 2 I don't want to change that in dropdown only if a i check value 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working Example http://jsfiddle.net/xv33z/

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function () {
var x = $("#test").val();
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        var y = $(this).val();
        if (x < y) {
            $("#test").val($(this).val());
        }
    }
});
```

First we save the current value of #test any time a new checkbox is checked. Then we get the value of the checkbox. If the value of the checkbox is greater than the value of the select box, then we update the select box.